# How to sort by values in a column based on identifiers in a different column in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

This would be our input:

| NAME | YEAR | VALUES |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2001 | 10 |
| A | 2000 | 5 |
| A | TOTAL | 15 |
| B | 2010 | 3 |
| B | 2011 | 7 |
| B | TOTAL | 10 |

We have to sort this table by ascending values of 'TOTAL' and then by ascending values of YEAR within the same NAME.

This would be our output:

| NAME | YEAR | VALUES |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B | 2010 | 3 |
| B | 2011 | 7 |
| B | TOTAL | 10 |
| A | 2000 | 5 |
| A | 2001 | 10 |
| A | TOTAL | 15 |

Answer (score 1):

I think I'd sum all values partitioned by name in a CTE, sort by them, then name, then year (with a special case for total)

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, SUM(values) OVER(PARTITION BY name) as sumval
    FROM yourdata
)

SELECT name, year, values
FROM cte
ORDER BY sumval, name, CASE WHEN year = 'TOTAL' THEN '9999' ELSE year end
```

You could also join your data to itself on just the total lines, meaning every row of yourdata ends up with an associated totals row:

```
SELECT yourdata.*
FROM
  yourdata
  INNER JOIN (SELECT name, values FROM yourdata WHERE year = 'TOTAL') t
  ON t.name = yourdata.name
ORDER BY
  t.values, yourdata.name, CASE WHEN year = 'TOTAL' THEN '9999' ELSE year end
```

e.g.

```
B   2010    3   TOTAL   10
B   2011    7   TOTAL   10
B   TOTAL   10  TOTAL   10
A   2000    5   TOTAL   15
A   2001    10  TOTAL   10
A   TOTAL   15  TOTAL   10
```

The final column is the total row for the name repeated over and over, so you can sort by the total, then by name to break ties, then by year (with 9999 to put the total after the numeric years)